# PIVOT for turning rows into columns in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I've got a complex requirement and I'm not sure if PIVOT can get it done.
 So, I've got a SQL table "Employee" which has all the employee data (primary key: EmployeeId). This table is having a foreign key link with "Pricing" table (join EmployeeId).

 My requirement is to display the result with each employeeId as columns and row being the TOP latest price for that employee.
I can get the pricing information from "Pricing" table by a simple join like:
Select TOP (Price) from Pricing p JOIN Employee e on e.EmployeeID = p.EmployeeID order by PDate Desc

But I'm not sure how to  use PIVOT for these.

Thanks

Comment: Do you only want one row (the top value) for all employees? If you have access to Crystal Reports, SSRS  and/or Excel, is there a reason you don't want to do this in a crosstab or pivot table?

Comment: Hi, Yes I want these records in one row. Also, I do not have access to crystal report.